# Magento 2.4.3 - Magento Cron for index

Tags: magento2.4.3, magento-cron, deadlock

We have some issues and I have been told is because we have our Magento cron set to execute every 1 min. But since our installation is so big with tons of product etc we need to raise it to go less frequently.

What is the recommended frequency for Magento cron for index to go for big store like us?

Comment: I would like to recommend: RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

Magento cron configuration should be every 1 min. There are different cron groups like default, index etc. You should pick and choose the right cron group for your custom cron setup to avoid server stress. You can also create your own cron group and configure as needed. Check this out.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/configure-cron-jobs.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Lots of info missing from this question.

Why should you change your cron schedule (what problem exists)? What does "tons of products etc" mean exactly?

As already pointed out, 1 min should be fine. The problem is almost always somewhere else - wrong indexer mode, bad ERP/PIM integration design, wrong hosting.

If you add some details, maybe we can give more advice.